# Foreach Loop in java

Tags: java

```
for(int i:arr)
    arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
```

Can we accept with this syntax?

I am trying to accept element using for-each loop in Java and while printing the value it is giving garbage value

Comment: The *syntax* is fine, but it does the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3):

This won't work.

```
for(int i:arr)
    arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
```

`i` has value of the array element, not the index value.

Or you need to initialise the array like and then set the value at the index:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < len; i++)
    arr[i] = i;

for(int i:arr)
    arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterators return you the values in the array rather than the index itself and foreach basically uses iterators.

You should instead use a normal loop for this as shown:

```
for(int x=0;x<arr.length;x++){
    arr[x]=sc.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use this syntax as this will only update the zero index in the array and will be updated by the last input value from the user in the 0th index of the array.

Let's say you have a `3` sized array and you give `3 2 1` as input from the user then only the first index of the array will be updated and at last, it will be containing the last input by the user. So finally the array will be `[1 0 0]` instead of `[3 2 1]` which is actually desired.

So to overcome this issue you have to use the normal for loop.